# grails dynamic select in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

Well it's not so dynamic but will change it's contents depending on a set of fields in a domain.

I have 4 prices in 4 fields and then I have a field that point's which price is to be used.

I created a list of those prices to be selected some of the prices can be empty and should not show up in the list.

I used the beforeInsert in the domain where I created the list.
But I get only one string with each element separated by a ';' so in the select will contain only one string with all elements.

It must be something with type of list I generated so I need help to know how I should create this list properly.

The domain:

```
class Author {
    def String name
    def String email
    def BigDecimal price1
    def BigDecimal price2
    def BigDecimal price3
    def BigDecimal price4
    def String choosedCert
    def List<String> availableCert

    static transients = ['availableCert']

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:true
        email nullable:true
        price1 nullable:true
        price2 nullable:true
        price3 nullable:true
        price4 nullable:true
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
       availableCert = getAvailableCert()         
    }

    def List<String> getAvailableCert() {
        def List<String> sl = new ArrayList<String>()
        if (price1 != null) sl.add('FSC')
        if (price2 != null) sl.add('PEFC')
        if (price3 != null) sl.add('CW')
        if (price4 != null) sl.add('UC')
        return sl
    }
}
```

and the line in the gsp:

```
<g:select name="choosedCert" from="${author.availableCert}
 "value="${choosedCert}" />
```

//----------

After correcting my typo:

```
<g:select name="choosedCert" from="${author?.availableCert}" value='' />
```

But I still got problems:

When I select 'FSC' I get the value in choosedCert as 'FSC,' and if I then will select a new value e.g. 'UC' I'll get the value as UC,FSC.
This is an edit.gsp so after each update I'll get the selected value added to the existing value all time so after updating once more with 'PEFC' selected i'll get 'PEFC,UC,FSC' so the new value is first inserted and then the old value is added after.

Comment: It looks like you may be going about this wrongly, what is the base problem you are trying to solve? Why not use a single Map property, instead of hard-coding prices to strings?

Comment: I just want to get a SELECT in the GSP that list only the strings that correspond to correct price. I.e. if price1,price2 and price4 contains a price then the SELECT should contain strings 'FSC',PEFC' and 'UC'. And when a string is selected, that string should be set in 'choosedCert'. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're editing the scaffolding view you end up with 2 elements named choosedCert, ideally you'd need to create your own edit.gsp and render only the elements required but as an example I did the following.

Added an Author in BootStrap like so:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    new Author( name: 'Dave', email: 'myemail', price1: new BigDecimal(1), price2: new BigDecimal(2), choosedCert: 'FSC' ).save( failOnError: true )
}
```

Then edit the update action in AuthorController:

```
...
author.choosedCert = params.availableCert
author.save flush:true
...
```

Then in edit.gsp:

```
...
</fieldset>
    <g:select name="availableCert" from="${author.availableCert}" value="${author.choosedCert}" />
<fieldset class="buttons">
...
```

Clearly this is not ideal because you still have the choosedCert text element rendered by Grails and no styling has been applied to the drop down form element but if you change the drop down and update the correct value will be saved in the domain object's choosedCert.
Scaffolding is great for getting things going but does have limitations, eventually you'll end up writing your own gsp's and use services for the transaction leg work.

Comment: Yes, that was typos as you said. I used a little test project where I test different things so I just copied the essential parts but lost those brackets.But as you manage to make it work I took another look and found another typo. In the gsp-line I discovered that the doublequote before "value=" was to close, no space. So I fixed it by putting a space in between.

Comment: Sorry but I got more problems with it. This is an edit.gsp so after selecting a value i click update and get the value inserted. The problem is first, the value is saved with a ',' after it like 'FSC,' and if I make a new update with e.g. 'UC' selected it will be added in front of the old one as 'UC,FSC'. The leftmost will not have a','.

Comment: How are you retrieving the choosedCert and binding to domain after submission?

Comment: I do nothing more than you can see in my code. above. All is in the gsp-line. I used to use the "inlist" in the domain to make all happen but now when I need a dynamic list it's not possible using inlist. My comment before was wrong about the leftmost value - it did end with a ',' but it was not visible.

Comment: So you're using scaffolding controller?

Comment: Yes, I used "Generate All" to get my initial controllers an views.

Comment: Thanks, your last edit made it. Well this was only the test/lab-project, the real project is more handcrafted but this part will be like this at the beginning, now I can proceed develop the project further until I reach next stop ;-) I have a lot to learn here, it's a lot more than programming with DELPHI which I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

I prepare a simple gsp with your setup:

Domain class as:

```
class Author {
    String name
    String email
    BigDecimal price1
    BigDecimal price2
    BigDecimal price3
    BigDecimal price4
    String choosedCert
    List<String> availableCert

    static transients = ['availableCert']

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:true
        email nullable:true
        price1 nullable:true
        price2 nullable:true
        price3 nullable:true
        price4 nullable:true
        choosedCert nullable: true
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        availableCert = getAvailableCert()
    }

    def List<String> getAvailableCert() {
        def List<String> sl = new ArrayList<String>()
        if (price1 != null) sl.push('FSC')
        if (price2 != null) sl.push('PEFC')
        if (price3 != null) sl.push('CW')
        if (price4 != null) sl.push('UC')
        println sl
        return sl
    }
}
```

Controller as:

```
class AuthorController {
    static responseFormats = ['json']

    def index() {
        [author: Author.findByName('Dave')]
    }

    def update() {
        println(params)
    }
}
```

and index.gsp as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:form controller="author" action="update">
            <g:select name="choosedCert" from="${author?.availableCert}" value='' />
            <g:actionSubmit value="Update" />
        </g:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then when I check the params value in the output:
    [choosedCert:FSC, _action_Update:Update, controller:author, action:update]

Here `,` mentioned after `FSC` is just to seperate `choosedCert` value from `_action_Update`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, did your code worked or..? I can't see any significant difference from my code, do I miss somthing?

Comment: I mentioned the output what I am getting after I clicked on Update button i.e. params value I am getting. So can you refer this and try in your code and also your code seems correct to me, just you are reading the value received at controller side in a different way.

Comment: Whatever i pinged is tested in grails 3.2.4

Comment: Well, it was a step backwards, now all elements is listed on one line in the SELECT. I created a new gsp called index2 and a corresponding action in the controller. I change the name uf the old update in the controller and then I just copied your code. Maybe i could zip the whole project for you to check? I can't see any difference but it must somthing.